# How Do I include the " > " in this if condition | Bash Script

Tags: linux, bash, shell-script, scripting

```
 date=$(date +'%d-%m-%y')
  mkdir -p $date
  echo "Enter DB User";
  read DBUSER ;
  echo "Enter Password" ;
  read PASS ;
  echo "Enter DB Name" ;
  read DBNAME ;
  echo "Enter Dump file name with .sql"
  read DESTDUMP


if [ mysqldump -u$DBUSER -p$PASS $DBNAME > $DESTDUMP ] ; then 

mv $DESTDUMP.sql $date

rsync -RravhP $date $DESTINATION

else 

echo "DATABASE DUMP WENT WRONG. CHECK YOUR ENTRIES"

fi
```

During the "if" statement it gives an error and therefore this script goes to the "else" part. It gives me this output from the "if" statement

```
 + [ mysqldump -uuser1 -ppass1 db1 ]
 script: 21: [: mysqldump: unexpected operator
 + echo DATABASE DUMP WENT WRONG. CHECK YOUR ENTRIES
 DATABASE DUMP WENT WRONG. CHECK YOUR ENTRIES
```

Comment: Remove the brackets `[...]`.

Answer (score 3):

Square braces (`[ ... ]` or `[[ .. ]]`) are used for specific tests (see `man test`).  If you just want to see whether a command has successfully completed (i. e. given an exit code of `0`), do not use them.  Simply:

```
if command; then
   do_something
else
   do_something_else
fi
```

So, in your case:

```
if mysqldump -u$DBUSER -p$PASS $DBNAME > $DESTDUMP; then 
    mv $DESTDUMP.sql $date
    rsync -RravhP $date $DESTINATION
else 
    echo "DATABASE DUMP WENT WRONG. CHECK YOUR ENTRIES"
fi
```